# Java Beginner; Compilation Error with "endsWith" method

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in Java and am kinda confused why the below code outputs a compilation error.

Below is the code.

What did I do wrong?

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> words = List.of("Apple", "Bat", "Cat");

//        System.out.println("Apple".endsWith("le"));

        Iterator it = words.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            if (it.next().endsWith("at")) {
                it.remove();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare your iterator as `Iterator<String>` to tell the compiler `it.next()` will return a `String`, which has the `endsWith`, otherwise it will think `it.next()` will return an `Object`, which does not have `endsWith`.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn what **generics** are. You got error because you use raw type with iterator. Raw type means `Object` type, but method you want to call `endsWith()` is the method of `String` type. So you should declare your iterator like `Iterator<String>` to specify the type of generic. So that compiler knows the actual type of objects.
More about generics you can read here
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html